# Can I make windows file explorer treat underscore (_) as a word separator (for ctrl navigation)?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, filenames

I'm overhauling my folder structure and trying to come up with a good file-naming system. Underscore seems like a good field separator - less obtrusive than (-) and more portable than space.

When renaming files with long names / selecting parts of names, ctrl+right/left arrow key is convenient for navigation and selection over entire words, but it only seems to treat (-) and space as word separators.

Is there any way to make windows treat (_) as a separator as well, or a different navigation shortcut that does?

*Some text/code editors seem to have this feature and some don't...

*I'm working with windows 10, but I had the same problem with 8/8.1.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I find myself really wanting this as well